# How to access props in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I have a problem when passing props to child Component

I have 2 components: `PhotoList` and `Pagination`. In `PhotoList` component I passing 2 props is `currentPage` and `totalPage` for `Pagination` component.

```
<Pagination 
  totalPage={Math.floor(this.state.totalImages/30)+1}
  currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
  clicked={this.pageChanged}
/>
```

Inside `Pagination` component. I have a state and I want to compute `range` attribute based on `currentPage` value

```
state = {
    range: [],
    startPage: 1,
    maxVisibleButtons: 5
  }
```

The problem is when I access props in `componentDidMount`. I receive the `totalPage` is 1 instead of correct value (in my case is 37) and I got wrong value for `range` attribute in state

And another thing is any idea to re-compute `range` value whenever the value of `currentPage` changed?

Comment: What's in your this.state.totalImages ?

Comment: It is the number of the total page I got from backend server e.g In my case I got 37 pages of images

Comment: It's happening because componentDidMount only render once, since you are getting totalImage from server so initially totalPage value is 1 and thats why you see 1 in componentDidMount. For this you will have to use componentDidUpdate

Comment: I thought that componentDidMount is called after the component is rendered, right? So I think that at that time, props had passed into subComponent with the correct value, isn't it? And anyway, If I use componentDidMount when the props changed over time, does it update the state of sub component too?

Comment: componentDidMount will be called again of a child when its parent prop/state is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the value of `this.state.totalImages` is not available on initial render, so you need to recompute `range` whenever the relevant `props` change:

```js
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  state = {
    range: [],
    startPage: 1,
    maxVisibleButtons: 5
  }

  // Compute range and save into state
  computeRange() {
    const {totalPage} = this.props;
    const newRange = [/* Some range computation based on props*/];
    this.setState({ range: newRange });
  }

  // Initially compute range
  componentDidMount() {
    computeRange();
  }

  // Recompute range if total changed
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.props.totalPage !== prevProps.totalPage) {
      computeRange();
    }
  }
}
```

Or use functional component and `React.useMemo`:

```js
const Pagination = ({totalPage, currentPage, clicked}) => {
  const [startPage, setStartPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [maxVisibleButtons, setMaxVisibleButtons] = React.useState(5);
  const range = React.useMemo(() =>
    // Or whatever you do to compute the range
    new Array(totalPage)
      .fill(0)
      .map((el, index) => index+1
  ), [totalPage]);

  return (
    /* The render return */
  );
}
```